# Pegar o número do chip do telefone

Tags: android, android-studio

Gostaria de retornar o número do chip do celular.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String number = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
Toast.makeText(this, "Número: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Estou utilizando o android versão 8 e 5 para teste, na versão 5 não mostra nada retorna apenas o `Toast` com a `String` Número e na versão 8 da ele fecha o app.

coloquei esse código no `onCreate`.

No Logcat mostra essa mensagem:

```
No Logcat ele deu essa mensagem: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither user 10083 nor current process hasandroid.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.READ_SMS, or android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS
```

Alguém ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar voce precisa das permissoes de `READ_PHONE_STATE`, `READ_SMS`, `READ_PHONE_NUMBERS`

[getLine1Number()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number())

Comment: Coloquei essas permissões no 'AndroidManifest.xml' mas continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: As permissoes tem que ser dadas em tempo de execução. Mesmo que estejam no Manifest. Para fins de teste, podes aceder ao ecra de configurações do app e fornecer as permissoes manualmente. Mas o ideial é que a app mostre aquela popup ao utilizador

Comment: https://scache.vzw.com/kb/images/common/google_permissions.jpg consegues dar permissao aqui

Comment: Dei as permissões manual nos que tem disponível, Contatos, SMS e Telefone agora na versão 8 não da erro mostra apenas o Toast em branco.

Comment: Alguma coisa aparece no Logcat? Coloca a saida do Logcat na sua pergunta. Acho que pode ajudar

Comment: No Logcat ele deu essa mensagem: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither user 10083 nor current process hasandroid.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.READ_SMS, or android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS

Comment: Bom é isso. Permissão